# How can I write a script that displays the words "I should have studied" to stdou when run?

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, echo, stdout

How can I enter the contents of a script that when run would display the words "I should have studied" to stdout?

This is my best try:

```
#!/bin/bash
$ echo "I should have studied" | grep studied
```

I know that the first statement is necessary for the shell to execute my command. In the second one, I am using echo to print it and then the pipe operator for that command to be redirected to become the input of my other command. I am also using 'grep' to find any lines in that list which contain the string directory and to send those lines to standard output. Am I making some progress?

Comment: We don't like it here when people ask questions from their CS exams. We also don't like when people refuse to google. https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-2.html

Comment: perhaps you should think about the meaning of the text that you are trying to display

Comment: $ echo "I should have studied" | grep study

Comment: Sorry I am just a newbie that is trying to get it right, not to cheat on a test. That will never get you anywhere. I am sure you started somewhere too, and I thought that this was a great resource to do that.

Comment: If you've already got something you've attempted, [add it to the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/599616/edit). Folks are generally very happy to help fix an attempt, particularly one that shows a fair try. Tell us which bits you understand and which bits you don't, so people can explain their solutions in context

Comment: Thanks #roaima, I am taking baby steps here.

Comment: On linux, read the `execve` man page to learn more about how `#!` works.

Answer (score 0):

If you're typing directly at a shell you can

```
echo "I should have studied"
```

To create a script, all you do is put the commands you want to be run into a (text) file and use that file:

Using you preferred UNIX/Linux editor, create the file `study`. You can use any name you like (including one with a `.sh` suffix if you prefer). Add these two lines to it

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "I should have studied"
```

The first line declares that it's a `bash` shell script. You don't need to filter the output with `grep` as the `echo` command does enough all by itself. (Also notice you don't type the leading `$`; some people use this on StackExchange and other sites to show they're typing a command but personally I think it's confusing.) Now make the file executable so it can run like any other program on the system

```
chmod +x study
```

And run it

```
./study
```

The leading `./` tells the shell to look for the command in the current directory. If the script was in a system directory or otherwise in your search path (`$PATH`) you would be able just to type its name, `study` to run it - just like any other command.

For syntax checking, don't be afraid to use https://shellcheck.net/ as and when your scripts start to develop.

Comment: That helps a lot! I will start working on it right away. I so appreciate you providing such an educational experience in kindness. Thanks for helping to change my opinion on this website. After my initial responses, I was discouraged and made me feel like no using this resource ever again.